# Check unicode in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding

How can I check whether a character is a Unicode character or not with PHP?

Comment: You may want to clarify what exactly you mean with Unicode in this context. I doubt you'll encounter characters not defined in Unicode, so your check might simply return `true` in every case.

Comment: i want to get the code point of a unicode charecter. how it can be done..

Comment: @Rössel: I believe he wants to know if a string contains chars other than ASCII.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Actually you don't even need the mb_string extension:

```
if (strlen($string) != strlen(utf8_decode($string)))
{
    echo 'is unicode';
}
```

And to find the code point of a given character:

```
$ord = unpack('N', mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UCS-4BE', 'UTF-8'));

echo $ord[1];
```

Comment: it works perfectly with my Arabic unicode to determine RTL, Thanks :)

Comment: PHP 7.2 added [`mb_ord`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mb-ord.php) for finding the code point.

Answer (score 5):

you can try with

```
mb_check_encoding($s,"UTF-8")
```

[link](http://phpbuilder.com/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php)

Comment: This code seems working !!.. and it will be helpful if you could help me to find a function to get the code point of a unicode charecter ?

Comment: let $s be "somestring", so if (mb_check_encoding($s,"UTF-8")) then {the string is unicode} else {it is not unicode }

Answer (score 2):

You'd usually do something like:

```
if (mb_strlen($ch) != strlen($ch)) ...
```

I should add: strlen counts bytes, while mb_strlen counts characters (properly handling multi-byte characters, which I guess is what you're really talking about rather than unicode - as unicode also covers over a hundred single-byte characters indistinguishable from ASCII)

Comment: hi searlea,

thanks for your fast response ! this is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: ive checked this and getting the result like below 

<?php
$ch = 'രവീഷ്'; //my name in Malayalam
echo mb_strlen($ch)."<br/>";
echo strlen($ch)."<br/>";
if (mb_strlen($ch) != strlen($ch))
 echo "Unicode";
else
 echo "Non-Unicode";
?>

its giving the result 

15
15 
Non-unicode

what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Strings in PHP are bytestreams - not character streams. You can't actually have unicode strings in PHP; You need to encode your characters with some encoding. If you want to cover the entire unicode range, UTF-8 is the most obvious choice.

If you want to get the codepoint of a utf-8 encoded bytestream, you can use this library: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/php-utf8/

However, I wonder what exactly you need this for? Most likely, you can solve all your woes by simply using utf-8.

Comment: hi guys.. my simple requirement was to find the code point of byte stream and i got it through the library from http://hsivonen.iki.fi/php-utf8/!!

thanks a lot !!

Comment: I still don't really see what the problem you were solving in the first place was. I'm quite sure you are digging a hole for your self.

Answer (score 1):

A unicode character will ALWAYS have the most significant byte set no matter what the value of the character is or if it's part of a multi-byte unicode character or what.  You can't just check to see if the string has more bytes than characters since some unicode characters are only one byte.  If any character in a string's byte value is greater than 127, that string contains unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys .. Finally i got the answer i was looking for .

Got an include file from http://hsivonen.iki.fi/php-utf8/.

The following code solved my problem:

```
<?php
  require_once("utf8.inc");
  /*** create a unicode string ***/
  $s = "حملة إلا صلاتي";
  $out = utf8ToUnicode($s);
  for ($i=0;$i < strlen($s);$i++)
    echo dechex($out[$i]).".";
?>
```