# Validate session cookie value with regex

Tags: php, regex, session

I'm trying to validate a session cookie value with regex, I have done some test, but without any success...could someone write and explain me how to match a non-ASCII character, spaces(\s), comma and semicolon (basically all the forbidden characters of a session value)? Obviously if one of those character is found the entire line is invalid.
At this moment my function is this:

```
session_name("RazorphynSupport");

if(isset($_COOKIE['RazorphynSupport']) && !is_string($_COOKIE['RazorphynSupport']) || !preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]{26,40}$/',$_COOKIE['RazorphynSupport'])){
    setcookie(session_name(),'invalid',time()-3600);
    //return error
    exit();
}
session_start(); 

//Logout
if($_POST[$_SESSION['token']['act']]=='logout' && isset($_SESSION['status'])){
    //Logout
}

//Session Check
if(isset($_SESSION['time']) && time()-$_SESSION['time']<=1800)
    $_SESSION['time']=time();
else if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && !isset($_SESSION['time']) || isset($_SESSION['time']) && time()-$_SESSION['time']>1800){
    //Destroy session; return error

    exit();
}
else if(isset($_SESSION['ip']) && $_SESSION['ip']!=retrive_ip()){
    //Destroy session; return error

    exit();
}
else if(!isset($_POST[$_SESSION['token']['act']]) && !isset($_POST['act']) && $_POST['act']!='faq_rating' || $_POST['token']!=$_SESSION['token']['faq']){
    //Destroy session; return error

    exit();
}
```

Before the `session_start()`, but obviously it's wrong.
 My problem is that if the session contains any illegal character the session_start function return an error, so to prevent it I would like to check the "integrity" of the cookie
**EDIT**
form firebug cookie tab:

```
Cookie Name -> RazorphynSupport

Value -> ETpSx-T6VFuIYS3fejyaq0
```

I need to validate `ETpSx-T6VFuIYS3fejyaq0` (that is a random generated string)

Comment: Don't use regex for it. Work with `Date` object

Comment: @Victor could you give me a reference?

Comment: I thought so, check my answer

Comment: @Victor reduced the code size

Comment: But what are you want to validate exactly? In session I can store anything: date, id, token, etc..

Comment: Is lenth of `ETpSx-T6VFuIYS3fejyaq0` string will be always 22 chars?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of listing the things that you will deny, you should list the things that you will allow.

I am reminded of [this TheDailyWTF story](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Pretty-Basic-Validation.aspx).

What do you expect in a session cookie? (By which I will assume you mean the value of a session cookie, which is a session id) Is it a hexadecimal string? How long? 32 bytes? 256? Something else entirely? Let's say your cookies are a 32 byte hexacimal string. Then the following regex will catch them:

```
/^[a-f0-9]{32}$/
```

Anything not matching that regex is known to be invalid.

However, there's a much more important step to take: you should check whether you actually have a session with that id that has not been expired yet.

Comment: I have updated the question, actually I have done some reserches and: it's lenght could be {22,40} and it cannot contain non-ASCII character, spaces, colon and semicolon

Comment: But what *can* it contain? Far more important. Only list the things that you'll allow, reject everything else.

Let's put it another way: you are member of a super secret treehouse club. If someone wants to go into the treehouse, they must give a valid password to the member who is the Doorman of the Day. So the Doorman of the Day has a list on him to match passwords against. What would you put on that list? Everything that is not a valid password, or just the small collection of correct passwords?

Comment: Ok, I have got and know it, the problem is that as far as I can see servers have different behaviour, mine uses only letters and numbers, another one even the underscore, so I have surfed the web and seems that that value could contain anything except non-ASCII, colon and semicolon... has it got sense to do a list of all the allowed characters? Also I don't know almost anythihng about regex, so maybe a shortcut for the allowed characters exist, but I'm not aware of it, so I'm asking

Comment: If you really insist on that, you should take two steps.

1. make sure it's just ASCII indeed. [Here is a way to detect if the string contains non-ASCII unicode characters in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350758/check-unicode-in-php).

2. `/^([^:;]|\S)+$/` -- but since PHP's implementation of regex is weird, that should be written as `/^([^:;]|\\S)+$/`

Comment: I didn't know about `[^]`, in this case I have to merge `[[:ascii:]]` with `[^;,\s]`, could you help me?

Comment: I thought you said colon and semicolon, but your code seems to deal with a semicolon and a comma. Which is it? Anyway, try `[^[:ascii:];,\s]`

Comment: My bad it's comma, sorry. However `[:ascii:]` means every ASCII code, so I tought about: "I accept every `[:ascii:]` except for `;,\s` (so `[^;,\s]`)", `[^[:ascii:];,\s]` will accept only non-ASCII

Comment: You're right. `[^[:^ascii:];,\s]` but see [the friendly manual](http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.character-classes.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this pattern:

```
if ( preg_match('/^[^:; ]+$/i', 'ETpSx-T6VFuIYS3fejyaq0') ) {
    // valid
}
```

this pattern allowed using digits, letters `a-z` in uppercase and lowercase, and also hyphen `-`.

Comment: The problem is that I need all the ASCII character excep spaces (\s), colon and semicolon

Comment: So, try to use `[^:; ]` for except `:; ` chars. Also you can add in `[]` any chars, that need to denied.

Comment: What chars is not `ASCII` for example?

Comment: This is an example: ابت

Comment: Hm, it's problemly. I think you need to allow all ASCII characters manually in `[]`