# Will comparing the binary data of a string with an unknown character encoding validate what its encoding is?

Tags: php, validation, utf-8, character-encoding

I need to *automatically* determine the character encoding of strings from email content and headers. For the most part this isn't an issue however there is an occasional email with content and/or a header that has an oddball character such as an [en dash](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm). Now I received an answer that technically seems to work if I statically test it on a specific header for a specific email however that blatantly ignores the fact that importing email needs to be a completely automated process in which case I am utterly unable to automatically determine the string's character encoding.

I've started with the basics such as detecting common trouble characters that seem to guarantee a character encoding issue will occur. However `strpos('en dash: –', '–')` works fine while *intentionally / manually* testing though it fails outright when added directly to the automated process. I'm going to guess that the issue there is that the string parameters have a UTF-8 encoding while the automated process is testing a string that isn't yet UTF-8 and thus internally the same character isn't using the same subset of code (via character encoding).

So my second attempt was [mb_detect_encoding](https://php.net/mb_detect_encoding)'s second parameter can be an array. So I tried the following:

```
$encodings = array('UTF-8','UCS-4','UCS-4BE','UCS-4LE','UCS-2','UCS-2BE','UCS-2LE','UTF-32','UTF-32BE','UTF-32LE','UTF-16','UTF-16BE','UTF-16LE','UTF-7','UTF7-IMAP','ASCII','EUC-JP','SJIS','eucJP-win','SJIS-win','ISO-2022-JP','ISO-2022-JP-MS','CP932','CP51932','SJIS-mac','SJIS-Mobile#DOCOMO','SJIS-Mobile#KDDI','SJIS-Mobile#SOFTBANK','UTF-8-Mobile#DOCOMO','UTF-8-Mobile#KDDI-A','UTF-8-Mobile#KDDI-B','UTF-8-Mobile#SOFTBANK','ISO-2022-JP-MOBILE#KDDI','JIS','JIS-ms','CP50220','CP50220raw','CP50221','CP50222','ISO-8859-1','ISO-8859-2','ISO-8859-3','ISO-8859-4','ISO-8859-5','ISO-8859-6','ISO-8859-7','ISO-8859-8','ISO-8859-9','ISO-8859-10','ISO-8859-13','ISO-8859-14','ISO-8859-15','ISO-8859-16','byte2be','byte2le','byte4be','byte4le','BASE64','HTML-ENTITIES','7bit','8bit','EUC-CN','CP936','GB18030','HZ','EUC-TW','CP950','BIG-5','EUC-KR','UHC','ISO-2022-KR','Windows-1251','Windows-1252','CP866','KOI8-R','KOI8-U','ArmSCII-8');
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($s, $encodings, true);
$compare = mb_convert_encoding($s, 'UTF-8', $encoding);

foreach ($encodings as $k1)
{
 if (mb_convert_encoding($s, 'UTF-8', $k1) === $s) {$encoding = $k1; break;}
}
```

Unfortunately that seemed to result in the same failure based on what I presume was the same underlying issue.

So my third idea I'm looking for some more experienced validation. I could convert the string down in its binary form (ones and zeroes, *not* binary data). Then I could try converting the string and then converting that second string to binary to compare the two binary versions; if they `===` match then I might have determined the correct character encoding?

Now I can easily try this [with this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6382880/606371) from an unrelated thread however I'm not certain if this is a valid idea or not. This is all intended to answer my question:

How can I determine the actual character encoding of a string in order to convert it to UTF-8 with fully automated validation without corrupting data?

By validation I'm talking about stuff like comparing the binary data though again, I'm not certain if that is a valid approach or not. I do know that I absolutely hate en dashes though.

Answer (score 1):

[The answer won't change: it's impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64985722/4299358). You have to rely on external information which encoding is used on text.

Guessing an encoding can horribly go wrong:

- Based on the order in which you test against it can either turn out as i.e. **ASCII** or **UTF-8** or **Windows-1252**, just because so far it fits in. Your list is questionable, because it may match **[Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)** which is not even a *text* encoding.
- If the source is not properly encoded itself then guessing its encoding will most likely exclude the correct one. And guess a wrong one. Which makes things worse.
- Many encodings share the same area: the source can either fit i.e. **Windows-1252** or **Windows-1251** and even detecting the lexical sense of the text cannot guarantee which of both is correct.

Also: ones and zeroes *are* binary. [PHP strings are only byte arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details), so they're binary to begin with. How they're interpreted relies on you: if your code is `$text= "グリーン";` then it's up to which encoding your PHP text file has and how your [PHP defaults](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) are set. There is no "*internal ... character*", only bytes. Which is also the reason why there are functions which operate on bytes (i.e. [`strlen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)) and on a specific text encoding (i.e. [`mb_strlen()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php)).

If you hate single characters or not: they can be easily used as what they are: characters in texts. And [–](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash) has its own valid meaning in contrast to [—](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash) and [‒](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Figure_dash) and [-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen-minus); don't replace it by personal opinion, because that could corrupt a context's meaning. It's like ignoring the fact that [A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A) and [Α](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha) and [A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_(Cyrillic)) are all different characters. You might want to look up the difference between [*homo*glyphs and *syno*glyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph) - the latter is your current perspective.

You may ask "*And in which encoding does PHP interpret the scripts?*" Luckily **ASCII** is for most encodings the most common denominator, so interpreting the first bytes of a file as such to search for `<?php` (all these are **ASCII** characters, so for PHP code itself it doesn't matter if it is effectively **UTF-8** or **ISO-8859-1** or **Shift-JIS**) will only fail when the document is encoded in i.e. **UTF-16** - in that case you must set your PHP defaults to that encoding. Which again proves: text encodings must be told outside of the text.

Comment: I was essentially asking if `00000001 === 00000001`, not sure why you validated my question in the reverse context as if I was arguing against it. I also prefer to maintain the original characters and over the past week have improved the conversions to UTF-8 to retain the original characters as intended by the author.

Comment: In PHP leading zeroes would be [octal literals - binary literals have the prefix `0b`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#example-33), i.e. `0b00000001`. "_over the past week_" - so, your question is no longer relevant?

Comment: What you've posted has use though like I said I've managed to improve conversions to UTF-8 in other areas since I posted the question.